# Phonegap Build / geolocation on iOS

Tags: ios, geolocation, location, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am using phonegap build
 - Phonegap CLI 7.0.1

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm"/>

 <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
```

My problem is, when I start the app I don't have a dialog box prompting the user to allow geolocation.
and when I go to the app settings, 
I only have notifications
Background App refresh
Cellular Data

How can I enable geolocation ?

Thanks

Comment: also I have this in my index.html

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Android, which notifies of permissions on installation, iOS doesn't ask for permissions until the app attempts to access the feature. I just tested this, and iOS didn't ask for location permission until I called `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` (`cli-7.0.1`).

Note: you can simplify your plugin declaration to:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" />
```

The `gap:` is deprecated, and npm is the default (no harm in leaving it). Might be worth locking to a version though othewise it will upgrade to new releases without your knowledge. You don't need the `feature tag`, the [geolocation plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/plugin.xml#L93) includes that for you.